# Bootstrap Accordion issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I was follow a video tutorial and demo about bootstrap accordion its work fine but have one issue i have to click to open every row for the accordion  and click itself again to close i want to be toggle when click other one the first close and so on 
**first here screen shot to get what i mean easily:**
http://www.4shared.com/download/xNSLTB57/accordoineIssue.PNG

**Now here the code:**

```
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" href="#first" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">First</a>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="first">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <img src="images/lebowski-1.jpg" alt="1" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" href="#secound" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                    Secound</a>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="secound">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <img src="images/lebowski-2.jpg" alt="2" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" href="#third" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">Third</a>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="third">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <img src="images/lebowski-3.jpg" alt="3" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Last here what it suppose to work:**
http://www.4shared.com/download/GuM54zUE/Capture.PNG

Comment: please tell us bootstrap version also

Comment: quite sure the class should be ```collapse``` and not ```collapsed```

Comment: is bootstrap.css and js included in your index file?

Comment: yes   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/amelia-bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#first">First</a>
            </div>
        </div><!--Here heading has to close and collapse has to start-->
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="first">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <img src="images/lebowski-1.jpg" alt="1" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" href="#secound" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                    Secound</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="secound">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <img src="images/lebowski-2.jpg" alt="2" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" href="#third" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">Third</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="third">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <img src="images/lebowski-3.jpg" alt="3" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M5NPd/)

Answer (score 0):

seems to be an issue with the nesting of divs

```
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a href="#first" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">First</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="first">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <img src="images/lebowski-1.jpg" alt="1" />
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a  href="#secound" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                Secound</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="secound">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <img src="images/lebowski-2.jpg" alt="2" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a href="#third" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">Third</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="third">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <img src="images/lebowski-3.jpg" alt="3" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seelan/XmXZY/2/)